# Segmentation fault in loops in C

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, segmentation-fault, conditional-statements

I have a segmentation fault in the following code. I have tried many things and do many tests. According to  printf tests the fault happens in the conditional checking part of while loop when the result of loop is false. I changed the structure many times and in every attempt I get an segmentation fault in the same place. What can be the possible reasons and how to fix it?

```
char * str;
char path_[8] = "/dir1/f1";
strcpy(str, strtok(path_,"/"));
while(str != NULL &&  x< length){
length = calcLength();
str = strtok(NULL, "/");
x++;

}
```

Comment: Your `path` is too short. It has no space for null-terminator.

Comment: `strcpy(str, strtok(path_,"/"));` Where do you think, `str` points to? Do you have any space to copy the tokens?

Comment: `strcpy(str, strtok(path_,"/"));` ==> `str = strtok(path_,"/");`

Comment: Perhaps you should explain what's the goal of this code.

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. Then make sure that it compiles with **no warnings**.